# Where Does a Webpack Output Path of Root ('/') Output To In The Filesystem?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, yarn-workspaces

I'm looking at an existing webpack react project and the output path is set to '/'.
My understanding is that output path is an absolute path so that is setting the output for the build to the root dir - whatever that is on a Windows machine!
I have no idea how this is working or where it is putting the build (I've tried searching with no luck).
Does anyone know?
Maybe there is a dependency library we're using that makes this behave differently to my expectations?
Does setting the context make this change - I thought it only affected entry settings?
We are using, among other things webpack-dev-server and yarn workspaces.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because we are using webpack-dev-server.

From this page: https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/

The following answer:

webpack-dev-server doesn't write any output files after compiling. Instead, it keeps bundle files in memory and serves them as if they were real files mounted at the server's root path. If your page expects to find the bundle files on a different path, you can change this with the devMiddleware.publicPath option in the dev server's configuration.